# Are varargs allowed in a java enum constructor?

Tags: java, enums, constructor

```
enum MyEnum {
     A( 1, 2, 3, 4),
     B(1, 2),
     C(4, 5, 8, 8, 9);

    private MyEnum( int firstInt, int... otherInts ) {
     // do something with arguments, perhaps initialize a List
    }
}
```

Are there any problems with this? Any reasons not to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, this is perfectly legal. No reason not to do it if your program requires it.

Comment: i seem to be getting some weird class initialization errors when i tried this ... so i removed the var args and it worked. (note the the program compiled cleanly both ways).

probably did something i didn't notice ... oh well, the solution i came up with in the end is better (i think).

Comment: Just out of curiosity ... could you print the error message? I cannot see any reason at all this shouldn't work. In fact, I copy/pasted your code and it compiled and ran right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

it does work.
You should try to

```
private MyEnum(int... Ints )
```

With enums you need to make sure that you access them in a manner the initializes them.  A lot of the time an access is all that is needed

```
MyEnum bob = MyEnum.A;
```