# How to set a list as an Enum constant argument?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quarkus

How do I pass a `List` type value in the constant parameter?
In this case, this parameter is only for the PARS() constant.

```
public enum ParColumnsEnum {

    ID_DIST("codDist"),
    PARS("listValue...");

    private final String columnName;

    ParColumnsEnum(String columnName) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }

    public String columnName() {
        return columnName;
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I ended up not mentioning it in the post but it's a list of object and not a string.

```
List<Pares> pares;
```

Comment: If a method or constructor expects a String, then that is what you will have to pass into it. There is no way to pass a List into it. You either modify the code to accept a List instead of a String, or you make up your own String format that can be converted to a List on demand and add logic for that. (eG use "Value1;Value2;Value3" and then later split that String by semicolon or somthing similar)

Comment: Right. Do you have an example of how to do this conversion?

Comment: [How to convert a String into an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347856/how-to-convert-a-string-into-an-arraylist) - Contains examples how to convert a String where values are separated by comma into an ArrayList. What symbol is best used for separation depends on your use case. Eg If a list value itself can contain comma then using comma as separator is obviously not a good idea.

Comment: You might want to consider varargs. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372773/are-varargs-allowed-in-a-java-enum-constructor

Comment: I ended up not mentioning it in the post but it's a list of object and not a string. `List<Pares> pares;`

Comment: You can make another constructor, `private ParColumnsEnum(List<Pares> obj) {...}` which will initialize the constant in the appropriate way.

Comment: (A) Do you mean a list of objects of a specific class, or a list of `Object` objects? (B) No need to segregate this info in your question with “Update” label; integrate the info into the Question as it originally should have been written.

Comment: It is a list of Pares: `List<Pares>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums are objects instantiated from a class, like other objects and classes. So if you have only a single constructor, then every object instantiated must come through that single constructor using its single argument.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73139507/how-to-set-a-list-as-an-enum-constant-argument/73140525#comment129176207_73139507), one solution is for you to have *more than one* constructor.

Here is an example where either of two constructors populate either of two member fields.

```java
public enum ParColumnsEnum 
{
    ID_DIST( "codDist" ) ,
    PARS( List.of( LocalDate.now() , 42 , "purple" ) );

    // Member fields.
    // One of these two member fields is always null. Either is populated by either constructor, but never both. 
    private final String columnName;
    private final List< Object > list;

    //  2 constructors.

    ParColumnsEnum( String columnName ) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }

    ParColumnsEnum( List< Object > list ) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    // Accessors.

    public String columnName() {
        return this.columnName; // Might return null. 
    }

    public List< Object > list() {
        return this.list ; // Might return null. 
    }

}
```

Comment: Since both fields are marked as `final`, they both need to be provided with a value (otherwise it would not compile). They can be assigned either at the lines where they declared on inside the constructors.